# Fifty men and thirty woman are lined up at random. How do I find the expected number of men who have a woman standing next to them.

Tags: probability, statistics

Fi.fty men and thirty woman are lined up at random. How do I find the expected number of men who have a woman standing next to them.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 2):

Label the men $1,2,\dots,50$. For $i=1$ to $50$, let $X_i=1$ if Man $i$ has a woman standing next to him, and let $X_i=0$ otherwise.

The number $Y$ of men with a woman next to them is $X_1+\cdots+X_{50}$, so by the linearity of expectation $E(Y)=E(X_1)+\cdots+E(X_{50})$. This is $50E(X_1)$.

It remains to find $E(X_i)$, which is $\Pr(X_i=1)$. We find $\Pr(X_i=0)$. A man has **no woman** next to him if (i) he is at an end and has a man next to him or (ii) he is not at an end and has men on both sides.

The probability of (i) is $\frac{2}{80}\cdot \frac{49}{79}$.

The probability of (ii) is $\frac{78}{80}\cdot \frac{49}{79}\cdot\frac{48}{78}$.

Now we have all the information we need to find $E(Y)$.